# Contador de Digitos pares en C#

Tags: c#

Requiero un método que pueda contar los digitos pares en el lenguaje de programacion C#, gracias....

```
public void Contador_Digitos_Pares(int dato)
{
    //logica de la operacion.
    return dato;
}
```

Comment: ¿Que es lo que haz intentado? ¿Que llevas en la lógica de operación?

Comment: Hola bienvenido, ¿Podrias compartir lo que has intentado y cuales han sido tus resultados?

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! Aca no hacemos ejercicios, pero te podemos ayudar si intentas algo y te trabas en algun lugar en particular

Answer (score 1):

Podrías transformar tu número en `string` para así obtener la cantidad de dígitos, recorrerlos y verificar si es o no par

```
string numeroString = dato.ToString();
int numerosPares = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < numeroString.Length; i++)
{
    if ((int.Parse(numeroString[i].ToString()) % 2) == 0)
    {
        numerosPares++;
    }
}
Console.WriteLine("Total numeros pares: "+ numerosPares);
```

Comment: No fomenten el que se hagan preguntas sin intentos

Comment: Me parece @shop350, sin embargo no me parece los votos negativos a respuestas que responden la pregunta.

Answer (score 0):

Para verificar si un número es, o no par, lo mejor es utilizar chequear si, al dividirlo por 2, su resto es 0, en esencia, si la condición `num % 2 == 0` implica que `num` es par, luego, hay montones de posibilidades de hacer lo que buscas, una podría ser utilizando `foreach`

```
static int contarParesConForeach(int d)
{
    int cont = 0;
    foreach(char c in d.ToString())
    {
        if (Convert.ToInt16(c) % 2 == 0)
        {
            cont++;
        }
    }
    return cont;
}
```

Otro podría ser usando `Linq` con `Where` y `Count`

```
static int contarParesCount(int d) => d.ToString().Where(x => x % 2 == 0).Count();
```

Ambas funciones van a producir exactamente el mismo resultado

```
Console.WriteLine($"{contarParesConForeach(623)}");
//Output: 2
Console.WriteLine($"{contarParesCount(623)}");
//Output: 2
```

Answer (score -2):

[Una pagina donde encontraras metodos en C#](http://oasiseneldecierto.blogspot.com/2018/09/metodos-de-programacion-en-c.html)....Tengo la solución a tu problema, te recomendaria, que si los vas a utilizar en un button, coloques este método de bajo, no dentro de la acción del del button:[image: Metodo Contar_Digito()]

Comment: Bienvenido, porfavor no uses capturas de código, pega el código en la respuesta.